# No email sent in magento

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.7

I have installed magento 1.7 in `wamp->localhost`. When i want to send email to the customer from my admin panel "**The order email has been sent**.", this message appears but the email is not sent to the customer. What should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you first know if you had your smtp configured ? 
 - Did you configure your smpt on wamp ?

if not 
 http://keertikiran.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/send-test-emails-with-wampserver.html

Comment: now i have configured smtp for wamp but still no email is send but the success message appears every time.

Comment: You can test if you stmp is running write a litte php code create mailtest.php and add this code : if you got email your stmp is ok and need check your magento settings.  check a little example:

http://pastebin.com/yFu9UnQF

Comment: @SumanGhosh Hi, If  solution suggested by danywalls is working for you please inform us.

Comment: Yes this is helpfull but i cannot understand how can i send confirmation emails in magento.

Comment: then try read this example how to send email from magento http://dbhoopendra.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-send-email-in-magento.html#.UNGZVqz5V-M

Comment: @danywalls Hi, Do we need to make some changes in our Gmail account to make the email sending feature working? Thanks

Comment: Did you setup your code to using TLS (SSL), which is necessary to deliver mail to Google (ports 465 or 587). check this example with config in magento to use gmail.

http://www.betasix.net/using-external-smtp-server-gmail-in-magento/

Comment: @danywalls Have you tried what you mentioned?Is it working for you?

Comment: Thank you all.. I fix the error.. actually i have missed to set up the ssl properly.. Now its working fine..

Comment: nice when you finish the project, you can write a post with your experience :)

Answer (score 2):

You need some SMTP mail client on your localhost then only you can test the email sending feature from localhost.